Podman pod volume permissions when containers use different UID
I am working with a podman pod which consists of two containers.

Container foo has bind mount ./foo:/foo.
Process within the container which needs rw to /foo is runnning as UID 1000

Container bar has named volume bar:/bar.
Process within the container which needs rw to /bar is running as UID 999


If I set userns to keep-id:uid=1000:gid=1000 on the pod, then container bar user with UID 999 does not have rw access on the named volume bar.
If userns is omitted from the pod, then container bar has access to the named volume bar, but container foo does not have access to /foo.
These further attempts at resolving the issue have yielded no results:

Container foo starts its process with 1000 even when --user=999:999 is passed to it.
Container bar does not work properly when --user=1000:1000 is provided.


If you would not be using a pod, then it would  be possible to use podman run --keep-id:uid=1000:gid=1000 image1 and podman run --keep-id:uid=999:gid=999 image2, in other words different userns for each container. If you want to use a pod, maybe setfacl mydir could be used to give access to specific container UIDs.
